# Unloading Windows driver

Tags: c, windows, winapi, driver

some time ago I decided to learn how to write drivers. Unfortunatelly I didn't get too far because for testing the driver it is kinda important for you to be able to unload it without the need of restarting the machine. Now I got back to it but I am just not able to get past this on my own.

Now I suppose just to make the question more straight forward you sure want to see this:

```
VOID Unload(PDRIVER_Object DriverObject)
{
  DbgPrint("Unload\r\n");
}
```

and

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath)
{
  DbgPrint("Entry\r\n");
  pDriverObject->DriverUnload = Unload;

  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

In DbgView it prints the "Entry" message, but when unloading the driver it doesn't print the "Unload" one. Actually trying to stop the driver service changes it's status to NOT_STOPPABLE.
Then I have to restart if I want another try.
I work with Windows 7 and with same outcomes I have tried to do it booting up with TESTSIGNING ON and with no signiture required too. A little bit odd thing is the load doesn't work either unless I create device in the entry function. Only then I can find my driver with winobj in the \Driver directory. I have also tried it out on another machine with Win7 installation but it turned out local settings are not the issue. If you recognize this kind of kernel behaviour I would really like to hear it, thanks.

Actually if know about some programm that can load .sys and then is able to unload it, drop a link or name. Source codes not required, the executable should do.. or vice versa.. thanks.

Comment: Debug in a Virtual Machine with [VisualDDK](http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/)?

Comment: Does it work without VS's IDE?

Comment: @gbjbaanb: ok, that sure is some progress, the driver doesn't stay for too long but at least I can see the Unload message, thank you very much

Comment: @stupid_idiot ta. added as an answer for you. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962361/driver-load-unload-fails-if-windbg-attached-with-breakpoint?rq=1) answer for details of setting breakpoints in your driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was I linked with /driver:wdm because I read an older tutorial. That is wrong nowadays, you can only IoCreateDevice in DriverEntry in legacy drivers that means proper option is just /driver. Sorry I dont understand the behaviour of I/O manager, but if you are having the same problem, just get rid of that wdm flag and it will unload.

Answer (score 1):

Driver development - use [OSR Driver Loader](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157)